# Как работать закрыть окно после загрузки файла в Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

Использую vaadin 8. Вот мой код:

```
public class XlsReceiver implements Upload.Receiver, Upload.SucceededListener, Upload.FailedListener {
private File tempFile;
@Override
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Тип файла: "+mimeType);
        tempFile = File.createTempFile(filename,"xls");
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        System.out.println("privet "+tempFile.getName());
        return new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void uploadSucceeded(Upload.SucceededEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("TADAM!");
        File destinationFile = new File("src/main/" + event.getFilename());
        FileUtils.moveFile(tempFile, destinationFile);
        XlsFileParser.read(destinationFile);

        if (destinationFile.delete()){
            System.out.println("Удалили");
        }
        else System.out.println("Не удалили!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public void uploadFailed(Upload.FailedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Upload is Failed! "+event.getReason());
}
```

}

```
Upload upload=new Upload();
                XlsReceiver receiver=new XlsReceiver();
                upload.setReceiver(receiver);
                upload.addSucceededListener(receiver);
                Layout layout=new HorizontalLayout();
                upload.setImmediateMode(false);
                layout.addComponent(upload);
                Window window=new Window("Загрузка файла");
                window.setContent(layout);
                window.center();
                UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
```

как закрыть окно после загрузки? Понимаю что надо добавить Listener в window, который будет ждать когда произойдет определенное событие в моем случае это конец загрузки файла. Но как правильно их использовать не понимаю, если есть какие-то материалы по этому вопросу, прошу поделиться, так как не нашел их в инете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может кому-то поможет:

```
upload.addSucceededListener(new Upload.SucceededListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void uploadSucceeded(Upload.SucceededEvent event) {
                        window.close();
                        System.out.println("====Close window!!!======");
                    }
                });
```